# Eclipse format comments with /* or // at beginning of line?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Basically, I want the Eclipse Java formatter to format comments so the `/*` or `//` is at the beginning of the line, before the first tab.

Does anyone know of any setting that allows this? I notice that <kbd>Ctrl+/</kbd> *does* do it this way, but using Format undoes it.

Comment: IOW, you want to use a non-standard formatting "standard".

Comment: @HotLicks: For my own personal projects, yes, I think I should be able to use any kind of consistent standards I like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for

- Never indent line comments on first column
- Never indent block comments on first column

under Preferences / Java / Code Style / Formatter / Edit... / Comments (in Eclipse Juno SR1.)

Comment: Ah, *that* is what that means. I couldn't figure out what it did based on the example in the style editor. Thanks!